# What are the value will stored in "Sendtype" in job dataview?

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-views, sfmc-business-unit

In Job Dataview,what are values we will get under "Sendtype". (Sendtype - The type of send used in the job)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have found from my MC org:

The "Sendtype" value would be `ExactTargetSend` when you send to audiences in Marketing Cloud system.

In case you send to Salesforce audiences (from a Salesforce data extension for example), the "Sendtype" value would be `SalesforcePhoenix`